# NodeJS application not waiting for response from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, graphql

I'm trying to setup a NodeJS application with GraphiQL API and MySQL database connection. All of it seem to work until I'm trying to get the data that was fetched from the database be available for GraphQL to be able to do something with it.

Here we have the app.js file, which is the starting point of the backend. Assume that all the imports and declarations are valid.

```
app.use('/api', graphql({
    schema: buildSchema(schema),
    rootValue: resolvers,
    graphiql: true
}));
```

The rootValue is as follows.

```
const resolvers = {
    regions: () => {
        var a = manager.getRegions();
        console.log("a: " + a);
        return a;
    }
};
```

The manager object. I have the manager object incase I want to change database type in the future.

```
const manager = {
    getRegions : function() {
        console.log("getRegions entered...");
        return processQuery("regions");
    }
};
```

Finally, under the MySQL script we have.

```
const processQuery = (query) => {
    var res = null;
    switch (query) {
        case 'regions':
        default:
            db.query(SELECT_REGIONS_QUERY, (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    res = JSON.stringify(rows);
                    console.log("Stringify: " + res);
                }
            });
    }
    return res;
}
```

I've read numerous pages and even stackoverflow posts about Promise, callback functions and async/await but neither (atleast to code attempts made by me) seem to make the printout under the rootValue be printed last...

I saw an implementation done by Academind that uses MongoDB instead and he doesn't seem to have to care about this issue. Any ideas on how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: `processQuery` is a synchronous function `db.query` is *asynchronous*. `processQuery()` will run and return `res` as `null` before the callback to `db.query` fires.

Comment: @MarkMeyer : So how do I "solve" this with that in mind?

Answer (score 0):

What you can to is make the processQuery an asynchronous function and just wait for the db.query to be solved.

```
const processQuery = async (query) => {
    var res = null;
    switch (query) {
        case 'regions':
        default:
            await db.query(SELECT_REGIONS_QUERY, (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    res = JSON.stringify(rows);
                    console.log("Stringify: " + res);
                }
            });
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I've actually tried that implementation... but I read that async/await should be avoided? Also, from this I get that pesky Promise object and I don't understand how to get value out of it... It's a pain that I can't solve...